# Counting no. of sections in a repeating section group

Tags: infopath, infopath-rules, forms-7

I am using a simple Pizza order form, which contains some basic details and a toppings section - `Toppings`. It is a repeating section which contains a drop box to select the topping.

Now, each time a topping is added, I want a text field `ToppingTotal` to be updated with the number of toppings.

Here's what I did:

- Added a Rule on `Toppings` which runs whenever section is changed
- Set the action to set the value of `ToppingTotal` to `count(.)`

The rule does run each time a topping is added, but the value of `ToppingTotal` is set each time to `1`.

Can someone point in the right direction? Thanks.

Comment: Where you have added "set the action to set the value of ToppingTotal to count(.)" rule?

Comment: is it by any chance related to SharePoint ? You can post this in web forum instead

Comment: @Viraj On the `Toppings` section itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add function

> count(select Toppings from repeating section)

to value textbox from ToppingTotal property.

Comment: It worked! Can you explain why it worked on the `ToppingTotal` field and not the actual repeating section itself?

Comment: In repeating section, there are multiple Toppings. You have added this rule to each topping. So one Topping will return 1 count in ToppingTotal textbox. And other toppings overwrite count in ToppingTotal textbox.

Comment: Okay. It now works when I add toppings. But when I remove, it should decrease the count, which is not happening. Any clues?

Comment: Are you able to add rule to sub repeating group? or try to set postback always from property of ToppingTotal textbox.